# How can I count number of digits after decimal point

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I count the number of digits after decimal point in  SQL Server 2008?

Eg: `1.99999999495049E-05`

I need to know how many digits there are after the decimal point.

Comment: This is not obvious for a floating point type field. Can you not use a fixed point type instead?

Comment: What is the type of the field? `FLOAT`? `DECIMAL`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count the number of digits after decimal then the below query works fine.

```
SELECT LEN(SUBSTRING(cast(COLUMNNAME as varchar), CHARINDEX('.',COLUMNNAME ) + 1, 1000)) AS DIGITSAFTERDECIMALPOINTS 
FROM TABLENAME
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's superbly tricky. This sort of logic should get you there:

```
DECLARE @Value float(53) = 1.99999999495049E-5;
DECLARE @StringValue varchar(40) = CONVERT(varchar(40), @Value, 2);
DECLARE @ELocation int = CHARINDEX('e', @StringValue);
DECLARE @ExponentDigits int = 0 - CAST(SUBSTRING(@StringValue, @Elocation + 1, 40) AS int);
DECLARE @MantissaString varchar(40) = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@StringValue, 1, @ELocation - 1), '.', '');
DECLARE @NumberOfMantissaDigits int = LEN(CAST(CAST(REVERSE(@MantissaString) AS bigint) AS varchar(20)));

SELECT @ExponentDigits + @NumberOfMantissaDigits - 1 AS NumberOfDecimalPlaces;
```

I've left them all as separate statements so you can work out what's going on. I could put it all in a single line expression but I'd shudder to try and understand it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to count the number of digits after a decimal point in Teradata

```
SELECT LENGTH(SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME FROM POSITION('.' IN COLUMN_NAME) + 1 FOR 1000))
FROM TABLE
```